# C# - Call an object as argument of a function

Tags: c#, object, arguments

Happy New Year.

I am struggling to find a way to call an object in a function by using objects in the arguments. It is all about trying to translate a code I made in VB into C# but it does not sound that straightforward.

I tried to turn this :

```
            test = textbox_fill(txtbox_value, txtbox_object, 8, &H80000012)
```

[...]

```
Public Function textbox_fill(textbox_value_string As String, textbox_object As Object, value As String, text_forecolor_value As Double) As Boolean
    textbox_value_string = value
    textbox_object.Text = value
    textbox_object.ForeColor = text_forecolor_value
    textbox_fill = True
End Function
```

Into this in C#:

```
textbox_fill(txtbox_value, txtbox8object, "8", 0x80000012);
```

```
        bool textbox_fill(string textbox_value_string, object textbox_object as Object, string value, double text_forecolor_value)
        {
            textbox_value_string = value;
            textbox_object.Text = value;
            textbox_object.ForeColor = text_forecolor_value;
            return true;
        }
```

What I have done is the following but it displays errors for the .Text and .Forecolor.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: If the point of the method is to set the state of a `TextBox`, why is `textbox_object` declared as type `Object` in the first place instead of type `TextBox`?

Comment: What is the point of `textbox_value_string`? You overwrite the value passed in with `value` and then you never use it again anyway? If you started with VB code that made sense, it may be easier to translate it to C#.

Comment: "it displays errors for the .Text and .Forecolor" – The error message contains the name of the file and the line number where the error occurs, and it also tells you what the problem is. Since the only one who knows what those error messages say is you, nobody except you can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `Option Strict Off` in VB (I strongly recommend to set it `On` either on the top of all the VB files or in the project settings). `Option Strict Off` allows late binding and implicit typing. C# works always as it had [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement), [`Option Explicit On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) and [`Option Infer On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement) with the `var` keyword (C# doesn't have such a switches). Because an `object` does not have a `Text` or a `ForeColor` property, you cannot access them. Even if you assign a `TextBox` (or another `Control` to it.

If you intend to pass a `TextBox` as argument, then type this parameter as `TextBox`, because `TextBox` is a class and therefore a type:

```cs
bool textbox_fill(string text, TextBox textbox, string value, double forecolor)
```

Also, [ForeColor](https://System.Drawing.Color) is a `System.Drawing.Color`. Not a `double`. Note that `TextBox` inherits both of these properties from `Control`. Therefore, you could also type the parameter as `Control`. This would allow you to use this function with other types of controls.

```cs
bool FillControl(Control control, string text, Color foreColor)
{
    control.Text = text;
    control.ForeColor = foreColor;
    return true;
}
```

You can get a `Color` from numbers with various overloads of the [Color.FromArgb Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb).

I am not sure what this Boolean return value is about. It seems not to make a lot of sense to always return `true`. Consider declaring the return type as `void` and drop the return-statement. This is the C# way to declare a `Sub`.

Answer (score -1):

OK! After trying various things, I think I have found it. It seems to actually work.

```
bool textbox_fill(string textbox_value_string, TextBox textbox_object, string value, int text_forecolor_value)
{
    textbox_value_string = value;
    textbox_object.Text = value;
    textbox_object.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(text_forecolor_value);
    return true;
}
```

Note : I changed the type for the color because the way the color are coded is not exactly the same in VB, at least, not the one I used so far. Hope it will be useful to other people too.

Comment: Assigning to `textbox_value_string` makes no sense. What is that supposed to do?

Answer (score -2):

Why do you want to give `txtbox8object`(name of your textbox) as input to the function when you have access to it? try this:

```
    bool textbox_fill(string textbox_value_string, string value, double text_forecolor_value)
    {
        txtbox8object.Text = value;
        txtbox8object.ForeColor = text_forecolor_value;
        return true;
     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).